# Xcode NSSortDescriptor Error Thread 1: signal ABRT

Tags: ios, xcode, nssortdescriptor

Hi I'm creating a stocks application in the Objective-C Big Nerd Ranch 2nd edition book and at the end of each chapter theres a challenge and the chapter i'm on has a challenge which is add a method to BNRPortfolio that returns an NSArray of all its stock holdings, sorted alphabetically by symbol and then test it in main(). Everything works great except for this method(which is declared in the BNRPortfolio.h). It gives me this error: Thread 1: signal ABRT. And prints the message below in the console. The error report and what I think it is, is there is something happening the the sortDescriptorWithKey:@"symbol" part but the error appears on the [sortedBySymbolHoldings sortUsingDescriptors:@[s]]; part which is whats throwing me off. If you have any ideas on how to fix this your help is greatly appreciated thanks!

**Code in BNRPortfolio.m:**

```
- (NSArray *)holdingsSortedBySymbol
{
    NSSortDescriptor *s = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"symbol" ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray *sortedBySymbolHoldings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    sortedBySymbolHoldings = _stocks;
    [sortedBySymbolHoldings sortUsingDescriptors:@[s]];

    return sortedBySymbolHoldings;
}
```

**What it prints in the console:**

```
2014-02-06 16:18:26.309 Stocks[1286:303] Portfolio for UK has a value of £279.50
2014-02-06 16:18:26.311 Stocks[1286:303] Portfolio for US has a value of $12772.00
2014-02-06 16:18:26.311 Stocks[1286:303] Top 3 most valuable holdings: (
    "<BNRStockHolding: 0x100106e90>",
    "<BNRStockHolding: 0x100102f70>",
    "<BNRStockHolding: 0x100104c90>"
)
2014-02-06 16:18:26.312 Stocks[1286:303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<BNRStockHolding 0x100106e90> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key symbol.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85d5a41c __exceptionPreprocess + 172
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff8d933e75 objc_exception_throw + 43
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff85d59fc9 -[NSException raise] + 9
    3   Foundation                          0x00007fff8377e06e -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForUndefinedKey:] + 235
    4   Foundation                          0x00007fff83695406 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKey:] + 381
    5   Foundation                          0x00007fff836ad49f -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) valueForKeyPath:] + 334
    6   Foundation                          0x00007fff836ac04c _sortedObjectsUsingDescriptors + 394
    7   Foundation                          0x00007fff8370fbd6 -[NSMutableArray(NSKeyValueSorting) sortUsingDescriptors:] + 466
    8   Stocks                              0x0000000100002018 -[BNRPortfolio holdingsSortedBySymbol] + 264
    9   Stocks                              0x00000001000028c2 main + 1522
    10  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff84b005fd start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: This looks like it hits null item in the _stocks variable. What is in the _stocks variable?

Comment: at least one object in _stocks doesn't have a property or method `symbol`.

Comment: `sortedBySymbolHoldings = _stocks` overwrites the array you just initialized `sortedBySymbolHoldings` with.

Comment: BNRStockHolding seems not to have a key named symbol. Can you give info on BNRStockHolding declaration? And you would want to do: 

    return [_stocks sortUsingDescriptors:@[s]];